# Prove equivalence of two versions of Sylvester's determinant identity

Tags: matrices, determinant

[MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersDeterminantIdentity.html) presents the following two versions of Sylvester's determinant identity, relating to an $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbb{A}$:

First:
$$
|\mathbb{A}||A_{r\,s,p\,q}| = |A_{r,p}||A_{s,q}| - |A_{r,q}| |A_{s,p}|
$$

where $r$ and $s$ ($p$ and $q$) are sets that indicate which rows (columns) of $\mathbb{A}$ are retained (note: this may need to be replaced by 'deleted' - a MathWorld's mistake?)

Second:
$$
|\mathbb{A}|\left[ a_{k\,k}^{(k-1)}\right]^{n-k-1}
=
\left|
\begin{matrix}
a_{k+1\, k+1}^{(k)} & \cdots & a_{k+1\, n}^{(k)} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n\, k+1}^{(k)} & \cdots & a_{n\, n}^{(k)} \\
\end{matrix}\right|
$$

where

$$ 
a_{i\, j}^{(k)}
=
\left|
\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1\,k} & a_{1 \, j} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots& \vdots \\
a_{k\ 1} & \cdots & a_{k\,k}& a_{k\, j} \\
a_{i\ 1} & \cdots & a_{i\, k} & a_{i\, j} \\
\end{matrix}
\right|
$$

for  $k<i$, $j \leq n$.

Would anyone help me prove that these two versions are indeed equivalent?